# Is there a STATICFILES_IGNORE_PATTERN setting?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and Django deployments.

I'm trying to ignore certain static files on deployment using Django's staticfiles module. I can of course use the command: `python manage.py collectstatic -i *.filextension` but I was wondering if there's a setting that could be used from the settings file instead.

For example, this is a setting for excluding apps:

`STATICFILES_EXCLUDED_APPS = (
    # list of apps
)`

This can be set from the settings.py file. **Is there a similar setting for ignoring files?**

I've turned [the documentation](https://django-staticfiles.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/index.html#contents) with no luck, yet this seems like it should be a normal task for a deployment.

Comment: You should be looking at the [actual documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/). That app was merged into the django core years ago. The consensus nowadays is to manage multiple settings files. The development settings file will differ from the production settings file.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not do that. Here are the lines that corresponds with file ignoring in `collectstatic` command:

```
ignore_patterns = options['ignore_patterns']
if options['use_default_ignore_patterns']:
    ignore_patterns += ['CVS', '.*', '*~']
self.ignore_patterns = list(set(ignore_patterns))
```

The best way to achive your goal is to write a custom management command. You can use `django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.collectstatic` as an inspiration.